# Trouble understanding \titlelabel, \thesection, \thesubsection, \thetitle

Tags: titlesec

I am reading the document for `titlesec` package. There is a command called `\titlelabel{<lable-format>}` and the document says:

> "Changes the label format in sections, subsections, etc. A `\thetitle` command is provided which is respectively `\thesection`, `\thesubsection`, etc. The default value in standard classes is..."

I am wondering about what `\thetitle`, `\thesection`, `\thesubsection` do.

Answer (score 8):

The commands `\thesection`, `\thesubsection`, etc. are commands of any standard document class that show the actual formatted numeration  for `\section`, `\subsection`, etc. as. I mean that could print some like "3.3" or "III.c" depending of how they are defined.

For example,  in the article  document class by default `\thesection` is defined as `\@arabic\c@section` than mean `\arabic{section}` (here `section` without `\` is the name of the counter) whereas  for `\thesubsection` is `\thesection .\@arabic \c@subsection` (i.e, `\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}`), etc.

The `\thetitle` is a wildcard to the above comnands of the `titlesec` package, so after a `\section{}` will be `\csname thesection\endcsname` and after a `\subsection{}` will be `\csname thesubsection\endcsname`, etc. 
You can see in the next MWE how `\thetitle` change to be equal to `\thesection` or the `\thesubsection` depending on its position into the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle\quad---\quad} % "original" format beside \thetitle
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
This is the section \thesection \\
This is the subsection \thesubsection \\
This is the title \thetitle
\section{Second  section}
This is the section \thesection \\
This is the subsection \thesubsection \\
This is the title \thetitle
\subsection{First subsection}
This is the section \thesection \\
This is the subsection \thesubsection \\
This is the title \thetitle
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: I'm not understanding the documentation's "section, subsection, etc." comment.  Does this mean I can redefine the sections known as "\chapter" and/or "\part" or only "\section" and "\subsection" ?

Comment: @user12711 ? Yes, you can redefine almost anything in LaTeX  (if that is a good idea is another issue) .

Comment: I mean, "can I use the titlesec command called \titlelabel to change \chapter title labels, or is it specifically designed to be used with sections below the chapter section level, i.e., section, subsection, paragraph and subparagraph?" (I'd like to add some psfont dingbat \ding{etc} decorations before the word "CHAPTER" and after the section (number) )

Comment: @user12711 I see. No, `\titlelabel` is for label format in sections and inferior levels, but you can use   `\titleformat`, e.g.   `\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\centering\bfseries\huge}{\S\ Chapter \thechapter\ \S}{1em}{ --- }[\hrule]`. Run `texdoc titlesec` for more information.